# How to give sequence number for a documents in openerp v7.0?

Tags: odoo

How to give sequence number for a document created in Openerp v7.0.?

i create a new sequence for that in openerp .

Any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a sequence file and use it in _default method to assign it to field. For more check how sequence are used in `sale` module.